# need help with a systems of equations question

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have these systems of equations:

$$\frac{3}{4}x-\frac{1}{2}y=12$$

$$ax-by=9$$

If $a$ and $b$ are constants, what is $\frac{a}{b}$?

I know that no solutions means that LHS $=0$ basically. so i tried making the RHS equal to 36 by multiplying the top equation by 3 and bottom by 4. that way when i subtract the two, i have the LHS $=0$. however this didn't work. any other way i can do this? the answer is $\frac{3}{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Plugging $$y=\frac{3}{2}x-24$$in the second equation we get
$$ax-b\left(\frac{3}{2}x-24\right)=9$$
Can you finish?

Comment: oh my god im so dumb, thanks. i can accept your answer in 11 minutes and  i will do that then

Comment: Can *you* finish? If not, this isn't a hint.

Comment: yeah i can definitely solve now.

Comment: @user477465: I was actually talking to Sonnhard. While it is possible to solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a$ and $b,$ it is **impossible** to solve for $\frac ab$, unless there's information you haven't shared with us. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply first equation by $\frac 34$.

$\frac 9{16}x-\frac 38y=9$ is the same line than $ax-by=9$ so we can identify the coefficients.

Thus $\dfrac ab=\dfrac{9\times 8}{16\times 3}=\dfrac{3}{2}$ which you could have guessed earlier because it is exactly $\dfrac{\frac 34}{\frac 12}$ from the initial equation.

Solving the system, means your two equation are proportional, thus the ratio $\frac ab$ is constant, it is the **slope of the line**.

Comment: You are assuming that they are the same line, but on what basis? Are two lines $Ax-By=C$ and $ax-by=c$ automatically equal whenever $C=c$?

Comment: Please stop your nonsensical downvoting crusade, in this kind of problem it is implicitly assumed we solve $\forall x,y$.

Comment: In *what* type of problem?

Comment: Also, we cannot solve for all $x$ and $y,$ since $y$ varies as $x$ does.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you've left something out, this isn't solvable. For example, letting $y=\frac32 x-24$ and subbing in to the second equation, we get $$ax-\frac32 bx+24b=9,$$ so $$\left(a-\frac32b\right)x=9-24b.$$ From this, we can conclude either that $a-\frac32b=0$ and $9-24b=0$ (so that $a=\frac32b$ and $b=\frac38,$ so that $a=\frac9{16}$ and, indeed, $\frac ab=\frac32$) or that $$x=\frac{9-24b}{a-\frac32}=\frac{18-48b}{2a-3}.$$ In the latter case, we can then conclude that $$y=\frac{27-72b}{2a-3}-24=\frac{99-72b-48a}{2a-3}.$$ However, this tells us nothing about $a$ and $b$! As long as $a\ne-\frac32$ and $b\ne 0,$ $\frac{a}{b}$ could be literally anything. In fact, since $b$ can be $0,$ then $\frac{a}{b}$ need not even be defined!!

If you know (for example) that both equations are supposed to be for the same line, then you can solve it. The easiest way to do so is to note that the lines should have the same slope, since $\frac ab$ will be the slope; all you have to do, then, is convert them both to slope-intercept form, and you're done.

Comment: @downvoters: Please inform me if I've made a mistake, so I can rectify it.

Comment: Never mind. I found it on my own.

Comment: +1. Yes, the question does not specify whether the system of equations must have no solution, a unique solution or infinitely many solutions. The slope-intercept forms are $y=\frac32x-24$ and $y=\frac{a}{b}x-\frac 9b$, so $\frac ab=\frac32, b\ne \frac38$ (no solution), $\frac ab\ne \frac 32$ (unique solution) and $\frac ab=\frac32, b=\frac38$ (infinitely many solutions or same lines).